# JBoss logging with log4j2 and log4j2-jboss-logmanager with Keycloak 11 (Wildfly 20)

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, keycloak, log4j2

I'm trying to use log4j2 api with keycloak 11 (Wildfly 20 based) while leveraging on wildfly logging susbsytem configuration on a per deployment basis.

My deployment is made of an uber jar with the following dependencies in the pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logmanager</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j2-jboss-logmanager</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've set the following variables :

/subsystem=logging:write-attribute(name=add-logging-api-dependencies, value=false) to exclude wildfly logging api

/subsystem=logging:write-attribute(name=use-deployment-logging-config, value=false) to benefit form wildfly logging subsystem configuration

The issue is that the JBoss logmanager seems to not be able to find any logging handlers even the root handler from the standalone-ha.xml that I'm using :

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="io.jaegertracing.Configuration">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.keycloak">
            <level name="${env.KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL:INFO}"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="${env.ROOT_LOGLEVEL:INFO}"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: One minor thing to note is log4j2 is supported like this by default in WildFly 22. That said what is the reason for setting `add-logging-api-dependencies` to `false`? That should not be required since by default no log4j2 API's are added to a deployment until WildFly 22.

Comment: Good point. Setting the add-logging-api-dependencies to false is useless. I know that WildFly 22 supports log4j2 but I can't wait until Keycloak is migrated to Wildfly 22+ .

Comment: Does one of your applications use log4j2? If so are log messages not being logged?

Comment: Exactly. My application is using log4j2 and application's logs are not output to the console while keycloak and wildfly ones are .

Comment: Is it possible that log4j2-jboss-logmanager version 1.0.0 is only compatible with version 2.6.0 of the log4j2 api or is it the minimum version ?

Comment: No. The current version of WildFly is using it and 2.14.0 is the log4j2 API version it's using. Maybe check your deployment to make sure you don't have log4j-core or some other binding implementation is present.

Comment: I've made a test by just replacing log4j2-jboss-logmanager by log4j2-to-slf4j in my pom.xml and it works. I can see the logs in the console . But this is not what I want since it adds another layer. I will check my uber jar for unexpected log4j2 implementation bindings .

Comment: Yeah. Using log4j2-jboss-logmanager should definitely work. That's how it's done in WildFly itself :)